GPS Issue when driving
I just got a Pixel 7a. When I use google maps, I have no issues when I'm walking around. But once I start driving, it constantly looses connection with the GPS or it is really slow updating my location. However, once I gave the "Carrier Service" access to the precise location to my device, it fixed the issue. Do you folks know why? I'm assuming that it has something to do with A-GPS.

By "Carries Service" Android usually means location calculation based on cellular signal strength and cellular tower locations. Today Android is able to calculate locations that can be very precise. In urban areas that should get you your location precise enough for follow you when driving.
Does you car front window has a special coating or colored glass? Some metallic coatings can block or weaken signals and the GPS signal is already in normal state pretty weak.
A-GPS does not have an impact on the GPS update frequency. It just shortens the time until you get the first GPS position fix when starting using GPS. As the GPS receiver does not have to search for the visible GPS satellites, instead it can simply download the current GPS "almanach" that contains the satellite positions you may be able to see. Once that almanach has been downloaded or calculated GPS-A has no longer an impact on the GPS signal.

Nope because I've tried other devices and they work perfectly fine. I was in other vehicles and it had the same issue. It got fixed when I allowed "carrier service" to know my location.

@Jay A hardware problem e.g. of the GPS antenna would also be possible. I would recommend to shut down the phone completely to totally reset the GPS chip. I would also recommend using an app like GPS Status and check how many satellites the phone detects.  If you have  a second phone compare the found satellites.

As I have said, it has already been fixed after I allowed "carrier service" to know my location.

@Jay That may work at the moment but I am not sure if this will always be the solution. I would expect that in rural regions with less vell towers the position quality will be not very good. Therefore I fwould recommend checking if your GPS in the phone is working when driving.

As I have said, it is working now which means it works perfectly when i'm driving when previously it was not.
